# How to change app icon in manifest file programatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to say that when user insert there desire icon image as input and click on button then app icon automatically change in android. Or how to set ' activity-alias 'icon property programmatically, beacuse  we use these property to change app icon .Please help me to solve these problem ..

Comment: This will make your app identity/brand lost

Comment: But I want these feature

Comment: Neither of those things are supported by the OS.

Comment: make a widget. you cant change app icon

Comment: Let's say this is possible then it will become easy to fool every user by changing app logo to bigger brands like whatsapp, facebook and get their data as input by user. so forget about this function. Only Android os can modify icon after installing app.